# FactoryBoy assign attribute to attribute of SubFactory

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, factory-boy

In defining a ModelFactory in FactoryBoy, I need to access an attribute of another model created by SubFactory and assign it to this ModelFactory's attribute.

This is what I want to do:

```
import factory
class MyModelFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = MyModel

    created_by = factory.SubFactory(AdminUserFactory)**.id**
```

Obviously that doesn't work because there is no AdminUser object to access the id in the MyModelFactory class definition.

This is what I have done, but it is ugly:

```
import factory
class MyModelFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = MyModel

    dummy_created_by = factory.SubFactory(AdminUserFactory)
    created_by = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: o.dummy_created_by.id)

    @classmethod
    def _create(cls, target_class, *args, **kwargs):
        del kwargs['dummy_created_by']
        return super(MyModelFactory, cls)._created(
            target_class, *args, **kwargs)
```

I was trying to read through the [Factory_Boy docs](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/factory_boy-1.2.0/internals.html) but didn't see a class or function that would allow me to lazily access the attribute. Does Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just create the related model, and pass that object in to MyModelFactory.create()?

Comment: @BrianDant Yes you could definitely do that. I was just looking for a way of doing things all in one go and being as DRY as possible.

Answer (score 10):

From factoryboy 2.4.0 onwards you can use [exclude](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html?highlight=exclude#factory.FactoryOptions.exclude). This lets you add a parameter to the factory that won't be passed onto the model class

```
import factory
class MyModelFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    created_by = factory.SubFactory(AdminUserFactory)
    created_by_id = factory.LazyAttribute(lambda o: o.created_by.id)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        exclude = ['created_by']
```

I've shifted the OPs example to use `created_by_id` but you can rename it to make sense for you.

Answer (score 6):

Use [SelfAttribute](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.org/en/v2.3.1/reference.html?highlight=create#selfattribute):

```
class MyModelFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = MyModel
    dummy_created_by = factory.SubFactory(AdminUserFactory)
    created_by = factory.SelfAttribute('dummy_created_by.id')
```

Comment: What if I need to use `SelfAttribute` to assign the result of a method call, not an attribute?

Comment: Is it possible to get a child object of `dummy_created_by`? For example if `AdminUserFactory` creates an `AdminUser` with some `UserRight` child rows, can I get the UserRight list or IDs? Something like `created_by = factory.SelfAttribute('dummy_created_by__user_right.id')`?  (I realize I can factory.create the UserRights, I'm just trying to keep code neatly encapsulated.)

Comment: @nnyby did you find an answer to your question? Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Try to use [Mixer](https://github.com/klen/mixer):

```
from mixer.backend.django import mixer

mixer.blend(MyModel, created_by=lambda: mixer.blend(AdminUser).id)
```

Comment: Thanks @klen, I will have to check out mixer. But on this project we are committed to FactoryBoy, so am looking for a FactoryBoy resolution.